# Equivalent of this integral involving the Airy function

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, special-functions

I have a trouble giving an equivalent of this integral (and of course, Maple is unable to give it). Let $ \mathrm{Ai} $ denote the [Airy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) whose zeroes are denoted by $ 0 > \alpha_1 > \alpha_2 > \dots  $ (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) for a plot). I form the continuous function $ f_k $ defined by
\begin{align*}%$
f_k(x) := \frac{ \mathrm{Ai}(x) }{x - \alpha_k} \quad (x \neq \alpha_k), \qquad f_k(\alpha_k) = \mathrm{Ai}'(\alpha_k)
\end{align*}

> Question : I would like an equivalent of 
>   \begin{align*}%$
> g(x) := \int_{-\infty}^{-x} f_k(y)^2 dy
> \end{align*}
>   when $ x \to +\infty $.

Note that this last integral is well-defined due to the decay of $ x\mapsto \frac{1}{(x - \alpha_k)^2} $.

I thought about rescaling $ g(x) = x \int_{-\infty}^{-1} f_k(xt)^2 dt $ and use the equivalent of $ \mathrm{Ai} $ inside the integral, but the equivalent I get is not integrable...

Comment: I have already the case $ -x \to +\infty $ in fact :)